# Operator to allow 2nd parameter

Tags: javascript, operators

Firstly please excuse my phrasing here, quite new to JS.
I have the below JS code running and it works perfectly with the parameters set to colour the 'Assigned Mins' column in my table.
What I am looking to do is add a 2nd parameter where the same colouring and parmeters but adding a column called 'Pending'

```
        for(var i=0; i<columns.length; ++i) {
            if(columns[i].text == 'Assigned Mins') {
                columns[i].renderer = function (value, meta, rec) {
                    if(value > '0:19') {
                        meta.style = "background-color:red;font-weight:bold;color:white;";
                    }
                    else if(value > '0:09') {
                        meta.style = "background-color:orange;font-weight:bold;color:white;";
                    }
                    else {
                        meta.style = "background-color:green;font-weight:bold;color:white;";
                    }
                    return value;
```

I've tried:

```
            if(columns[i].text == 'Assigned Mins','Pending') {
```

and

```
            if(columns[i].text == 'Assigned Mins'||'Pending') {
```

and a few other variations using the || and && operators but either nothing happens or it colours all columns in the table.

As suggested I have also just tried the duplicate post (Check variable equality against a list of values) using:

```
if (['Assigned Mins','Pending'].indexOf(columns[i]) > -1)
```

and

```
if (~['Assigned Mins','Pending'].indexOf(columns[i]))
```

However in both cases the result is that none of the colouring works at all

Please can someone advise?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `if (columns[i].text == 'Assigned Mins' || columns[i].text == 'Pending') `?

Comment: Typo. Before you had `if(columns[i].text == 'Assigned Mins') {` but after you have `if (['Assigned Mins','Pending'].indexOf(columns[i]) > -1)` — what happened to the `.text`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should work. It's the solution you provided but you just forgot the .text

```
if (['Assigned Mins','Pending'].indexOf(columns[i].text) > -1)
```